# Addition of two ASCII values in c programming

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am receiving a hex value

```
uint8_t length = rx_dataframe.dlc// Current value of this in hex is 0x08
```

I am trying to get a char value("8") from this value. As per the ASCII table hex value of "8" is 0x38.
I have tried directly adding "0" but being confused in this

```
tx_buff_dlc[0]= (rx_dataframe.dlc)+"0";// I know its not currect but just thought
```

`tx_buff_dlc[0]=0x08+0x30` will be equal to `0x038` and will get "8"

Can someone please explain how are the addition for the hex value done in C

Comment: not sure if this is the problem but you should use +'0' , because ".." is a const char* value, while '0' is a single char.

Comment: This does not have anything to do with hex-values, nor hexadecimal values. BTW: Do you have all warnings enabled and do you read them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"0"` denotes a string, which has a particular address. The addition will give you some random location in memory, which is not what you want.

Instead, use *single* quotes: `'0'`. This will compile to whatever the value is for the character `'0'` (for ASCII, it's 0x30 as you mentioned). Then, the addition will work as intended.